# Looking for an algorithm to solve a specific Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: algorithms, optimization, traveling-salesman

I am trying to figure out a way to create routes for trucks to complete a list of orders(drops/stops), while *minimizing distance traveled*.

- There is only ever 1 company warehouse in the area.
- The trucks have to deliver *based on capacity*.
- Each truck can hold a maximum (usually 18 pallets).
- Each order will be for a number underneath that maximum.
- There will be a *maximum number of trucks* specified.
- When trucks are finished with their route, they will *return* to the company
  warehouse.

I already have all of the orders, the pallets they are requesting, and the distance between each point.

I am an absolute *simpleton* when it comes to complex problems like these...  I am hoping that someone has a simple (relatively) solution, or an article of some sort that could help me down my path.

Comment: underneath $\: \mapsto \:$ "which is at most" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: The maximum number of trucks only matters if there is some unmentioned constraint (perhaps a relevant time limit), since otherwise the truck with the highest maximum could just do all of the trips, returning to the warehouse between trips. $\;$

Comment: @Ricky, you are correct.  The maximum number of trucks does not matter here (although in practice we will allocate trucks so that they can be done in a timely manner).  The trucks will all be equal for a day (between 16 and 18).  They transport live goods which have a weight restriction, which changes based on how much rain they get.

Comment: I don't think I really understand the details of your problem specification, but you might look at integer linear programming: I suspect your problem could be specified as an integer linear program and then solved with an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  Spend some time doing some Googling and searching on this site and reading in textbooks to learn about ILP and how to use it, then see if it lets you do what you want.

Comment: Have you heard of the Traveling Salesman problem?

Comment: FYI [Unhappy Truckers and Other Algorithmic Problems](http://nautil.us/issue/3/in-transit/unhappy-truckers-and-other-algorithmic-problems)

Comment: Thank you for the responses!  @Guy, I read your link and it does explain the problem in simpler terms.  I am looking for a basic solution that attempts to minimize mileage without testing every possible route.

Comment: @Raphael, I have been reading many different articles and the TSP seems to be closely related to the VRP.  The only difference I could tell was that usually TSP was based on time and infinite capacity where VRP was based on mileage and limited capacity.  It is a very complicated issue, and is mostly over my head =(

Comment: @D.W. It will take a while before I can intelligently talk about ILP.  Thank you for the lead!

Answer (score -2):

A metaheuristic would do. I would opt for a Large Neighbourhood Search (LNS), a Genetic Algorithm (GA), or Tabu Search (TS).

Comment: This is rather vague. Can you give more detail? Why would those techniques work? Would any one of them be better than the others?